# When paging through a block, another block on the page disappears

Tags: 7, views, organic-groups, blocks

I am using Drupal 7 with Organic Groups and Views. Currently within my team node I have 2 blocks appearing with the proper filters in place. The first block is configured to only appear only on pages with the group content. The second block displays 1 item per page and has a pager appearing belong the content in order to page through the multiple nodes belonging to the block.

I have noticed whenever I go to another page through the pager at the bottom of block 2 the 1st block completely disappears. Am I suppose to configure the first block differently? I don't know what I am doing wrong.

**Edit**

I would also be willing to remove the pager and make it so that if you click the second block's title it brings you to an alternate page/view/block that displays all of the content yet I haven't figured out a way since then it isn't on a group page anymore and I don't know how to grab (or set it up to grab) the group id to filter the content by.

Comment: A couple of things come to mind. 1. On the block that disappears, does it have an argument that is defined by the URL? 2. or in your block settings, have you accounted for a wildcard for subsequent pages?